# Hidden easter egg

Tags: popularity-contest, game, obfuscation

Here's a fun idea:

Write a simple game (tic-tac-toe, guess the number, etc) that has an easter egg in it, that can be triggered by a specific, special input from the user and does something cool, but the code for the game does not appear to contain any easter eggs (or any obviously obfuscated code) at first glance.

This is a popularity contest, so highest vote by the community wins.

Comment: Nice idea, but you should have more specific requirements.  Please use the sandbox on meta to refine your question, then repost it.

Comment: I think the question is too clear: a simple game with an easter egg.

Answer (score 2):

### TI-BASIC

**Lock Screen** for your TI-84 calculator

```
:Repeat Str1="PASSWORD"
:Input Str1
:End
```

First one to find the egg gets a chicken ;)